# How can I make an order as paid after order status complete

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php

I'm facing a problem with the payment gateway after the order is paid by the gateway most of the time the order status will be complete and no invoice is created and not registered as paid.

Is it possible after the order status is complete to create an invoice and make it as paid?

[image: payment]

[image: invoice]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can create new order statuses and alter the existing ones in the

```
Stores > settings > Order Status
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qyi9.png

Now you have to Alter the existing one which says complete.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIHqa.png

You can change the Status Processing to Complete and Complete to Order Paid, You can also change the Status Code but I will not recommend that instead, I will recommend you to create new ones with

> Status code complete assign it to processing state

and

> Status code order_paid assign it to complete state

you can also check the option "Use Order Status As Default" so that whenever an order gets into that state it automatically gets assigned.

Follow these Instructions :

1. Click on the "Assign Status to State" button at the top and Assign the Existing complete Status to the Processing state

[image]

2. Click on "Create New Status" and set the Status "Order Paid" and code "order_paid"

[image]

3. Assign the newly created status "Order Paid" to the existing "Complete" State
   [image]

Comment: Thank you Manish Kumar For your answer.
I'm not sure how can I assign order_paid to complete
because I could not find order_paid on the list

Comment: Hello @mrwho, You need to create status first then there is button at the top to assign that newly created status to current states

Comment: I have added the steps you can follow this. You can accept this answer if that works for you. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to rest status as default after making a change?

Comment: I didn't got your question @mrwho